# GAE Go runtime SLA

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Where can I find the SLA and deprecation policy of GAE [Go runtime](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/).

As per the [features page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/features/),

```
The runtime is experimental,
Go
Experimental    The Go runtime executes your code in a Go 1.1 environment. This runtime is Experimental.    Release Notes   Documentation   SDK
```

But, core features are GA (Data storage, retrieval, and search, ...).

So, where can I see if Google decide not to support Go runtime in app engine, what deprecation policy would be in effect.

Thanks.

Comment: One of the points of saying `it's experimental` is to be able to back out of it. It also tells you that you should not rely on it, i.e. use it in production. In practice they have deprecated features with about 6 months notice (afaik Conversion API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: In April 2018 I no longer see any signs that Go support is experimental. You should research the current state of things rather than relying on the years-old answer below.

---

I think there is *no* deprecation policy for the Go runtime, not even a hard commitment to keep the service running, based on language in section 7.3 of [the TOS](https://developers.google.com/appengine/terms): 'This Deprecation Policy doesn't apply to versions, features, and functionality labeled as "experimental."' I'm not a lawyer.

In reality I don't think there are any signs Google is likely to shut it down for the short term. They haven't deprecated a language so far, the runtime has been out for a while and is still updated (SDK [released 2011](http://blog.golang.org/go-and-google-app-engine), and is [actively updated](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForGoReleaseNotes) as of Nov '13), it has users ([goread.io](http://goread.io/), [at least a couple little projects in Google](http://talks.golang.org/2013/highperf.slide)), and Go *is* a Google creation. But no one has promised continued support or backwards compatibility.

It's quite reasonable to be wary of lock-in with any platform/vendor, especially if they have no contractual obligations to you. It might be wise to ensure you can eventually port your app if needed (to Heroku, your own set of VMs, etc) by not relying too heavily on the quirks of GAE's datastore and other quirks.